# How to get the Local Time on a server in a different timezone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

I am from India and I have a shared server with GoDaddy in the US for hosting an ASP.net website.

When I Use `DateTime.Now` property I get the time in US.

How can I change it to Indian time for whole my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `TimeZoneInfo` is the best approach:

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
var now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZoneInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to change the timezone for an application, but you could replace all instances of DateTime.Now with a static class method that gets the current date and then adjusts it for the desired time zone.

For example:

```
        var dtDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        dtDate.AddHours(5);
        dtDate.AddMinutes(30);
        return dtDate;
```

Comment: Using `TimeZoneInfo` would be a better approach I think.

Comment: @DaveShaw: I thought about that approach, but it seemed like overkill. Assuming that the target system is always in a specific timezone (i.e. Chennai), converting to Utc, then adjusting for the timezone offset is a pretty straightforward operation.

Comment: The problem with adding the offset yourself is that you are hard-coding the offset value into your application.  What would happen if your user ran with the application for several years and one day the Indian government decided to change the timezone rules?  Maybe they would switch to +5:00 instead of +5:30, or perhaps they will adopt some form of daylight savings time.  More likely, what if the application is sold to someone who runs it in a different location?  The timezone Id string can be put in a user setting so it can easily be changed at runtime.